# Working with smb:// links

Tags: finder, network, mount, sharing, smb

I'm connected to an SMB share called `SHARE1`. I see it in the Finder, on my desktop, etc. with the name `SHARE1`

Let's say from the Finder, I right click on a file from it, choose Get Info, then copy the smb:// link. It's something like this:

```
smb://fs1.contoso.com/SHARE1/Path/To/The/File/File1.mov
```

When this link is opened, it doesn't simply open that file or the folder on `SHARE1` that's mounted already. Instead, it mounts *another* share called `File`, which is the name of the parent folder.

Now the Finder is connected to two network shares.

Has anyone discovered a way to make this behave nicely, and not mount a second network share? Why anyone would actually *prefer* SMB links open this way is beyond me.